# How to click on a position of form or a control automatically?

Tags: vb.net, events, visual-studio-2008, click, position

I'm using Visual Basic 2008 (VB.NET) and I have an old control which have some buttons on it. These buttons can not be pressed without actual click and the control have no event or API for that. The control is something like the picture below which has multiple objects and buttons as a single control which controls inside the control can be changed dynamically according to some conditions but at a fixed place and this is why I think simulating a click that I said is the best way in my opinion:
(The actual control is completely different that the picture below. It's only a sample)
[image]

I can click on the button by doing these steps:

1. Collecting all controls positions on my form
2. Moving the control in order to put the button exactly at the left top of the form

   > MyControl.Left = -43
   >   MyControl.Top = -6
3. Moving form exactly to the center of the screen

   > Me.Location = New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2 - 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2 - 1)
4. Simulating a click action at the center of the screen
5. Moving back controls to their positions that I got in the first step

It can be done that way but it's not reliable and it might not be user friendly for my program customers.

I want to ask if there are any better method to do that like simulating a click event on a position on the form itself (so I don't have to move controls and do other steps)?

Comment: I don't understand your purpose??

Comment: I see no issue, positioning controls any way you want. For example, I can select control `tab index`, and  click on any place on the form. I can get the `x-y` from my mouse click and set location of control there. Please be more clear

Comment: @OneFineDay I want to simulate an actual click on a button which is a part of a control. I'm going to add a picture of how control is.

Comment: May you show us the code that moves the form and simulates the click ?

Comment: Sorry, that did not clear anything up for me. Maybe edit your question with some pics of what you are talking about. And the code your currently using.

Comment: It sounds like (and looks like) the thing is a UserControl.  It seems like *that* control ought to have some way to programmatically  do Prev and Next, but buttons are for users to press, not code.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, something like UserControl. but it's not an actual usercontrol which can be controlled by the programmer. there is no way to do that programmatically.

Comment: @ Amirreza Nasiri : you didn't provide the code used to simulate the click at step 4.

Comment: Is this a WinForm Control?  If it is I can post some code that uses Reflection to determine **if** there are any fields in the user-control that can be cast to a Button type.  **If** there are, then it is possible get a reference to that Button and use PerformClick on it.  Basically, you  hack the user-control to determine what is there.  A alternative is to use a tool such as RedGates Reflector to inspect the code of the user-control to see how it is constructed.

Comment: @Graffito : Why do you thing that the code is needed at all? I'm talking about my method not my codes which I don't want to use because of their reliability.

Comment: @TnTinMn : unfortunately it's not :( the image is only a sample and the stuffs inside the control can be changed dynamically but at a fixed place. so I think simulating a click event on a fixed position of form is the best way instead of clicking on the screen after moving controls and etc.

Answer (score 2):

Of course I feel I must tell you that simulating a mouse click in order to programmatically click a button is not a very good idea. Many things can go wrong with this method (The form could move, making your mouse click on the wrong location; Form could be minimized, or another form could be on top of it, etc)

That said, it is possible, so take a look at this article that contains the code to simulate a mouse click.

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/276/simulating-mouse-events/

Once again, please consider doing this a different way. Iterate through the controls in the user control until you find the button you want and use button.performclick. Or you can call the function that the button.click event calls yourself, if it is public